# Why axios is returning Network Error when I have network connectivity?

Tags: react-native, axios

Following code sample is written to test retry scenarios, for which I am disabling/enabling Wifi connectivity in between. After enabling Wifi as well axios returns a *Network Error* with status as *ERR_NETWORK*.

```
async function fetchRecords(path:any, offset: number, columns?: any, retryCount?: number) : Promise<any> {
    const response : any = await GET(path);
    if (response && response.status == 200){
        return {
            data: response.data.result,
        };
    }else {
        if (retryCount && retryCount > 0){
            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 5000));
            retryCount = retryCount-1;
            return await fetchRecords(table, offset, columns, retryCount);
        }else {
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated**.
Error from Axios :
{
"message": "Network Error",
"name": "AxiosError",
"stack": "AxiosError: Network Error\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle .. )".
"code": "ERR_NETWORK",
"status": null.
}.

Comment: As this is React Native, do you know exactly which platform API that Axios is using to make requests? That would be a good starting point. Does Axios write anything to your logs or stdout/stderr?

Comment: This is in Xcode simulator for iOS, and I am making requests on button click. And axios error I have updated in original question
Thanks!

Comment: Can u clarify is this related to wifi turning on/off? E.g. On normal circumstances, your API is working properly.

Comment: Yes, in normal circumstances it works as expected i.e. with 200 response status.